# Call GO binary in .gitlab-ci.yml inside Script section and capture response

Tags: go, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am looking for a way to call main.go file from `.gitlab-ci.yml` File. Main.go accepts flag and returns boolean values.

From bash, I can execute below

```
go run ./cmd/main.go -timeout=10

It displays true/ false values.
```

Now from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, I want to call above program. We already have working set up (docker images) where all the GO/ SH binaries will be placed. So `.gitlab-ci.yml` file knows the location of above program. It is just that I am not finding way to call above binary in `.gitlab-ci.yml` inside scripts section. I should be able to capture return response of GO binary.

Comment: are you running your job in a self hosted runner?

Comment: Runner, docker images, Infra required for execution is Self Hosted. So from Git YML, I can call go run binary. But, the issue I am facing is capturing output returned by main.go and processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to debug this (this only works on self hosted runners)

Set in your .gitlab-ci.yml

```
script:
  - tail -f /dev/null
  - your commands
  - your commands ...
```

After run this job, your runner will freeze and you will be able to connect inside your runner container

`docker (or kubectl) exec -it <your runner container> bash`

after this, you can debug and test all of your commands and you will know the reason of why your commands are not working and you can fix it later in your gitlab file